# Is it Magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.8 version support ElasticSearch 7.1.1?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch

I am using Magento Version 2.2.3.

[image]

And my current version of Elastic Search is 6.2.4.

[image]

But my search result are not coming correct.Can I Update my ElasticSearch version to 7.1 or more in this magento 2.2.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

Up to v6 at the moment (April 2020) but that may change in future

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-overview.html

Can you provide more detail on what's wrong with results

You could of course look at third party extensions

Comment: Yes, I am using third party extension (Wyomind). But my result give issue like : i search drill in search bar . First 8 9 prodduct are of drill but other some else but i have more then 50 drill in my site which shown on 5 7 page if i search drill.

Comment: that's an issue we need result like : if i have 50 drils and i search drill then first 50 products of search result page must be drill afterthat other product shown.

Comment: Have you reached out to wyomind